# Should i keep the default Magento CSS classes when creating a new template?

Tags: template, theme, design

i am quite new in magento templating. I am creating a new theme based on Foundation framework.

My question is do i have to leave the default CSS classes of the base template?

If i delete them and create new classes does it occur any problem to any plugins?

Example 1 (Magento Base Template Classes):

```
<div class="account-create">
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Create an Account') ?></h1>
</div>
```

Example 2 (Magento with my own classes):

```
<div class="new-account">
<div class="mytitle">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Create an Account') ?></h1>
</div>
```

Example 3 (Magento Classes with my Classes);

```
<div class="account-create new-account">
<div class="page-title mytitle">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Create an Account') ?></h1>
</div>
```

Which example i should follow 2 or 3?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All approaches are valid.
this is a matter of choosing your weapon.
You can create a theme just by editing the css file and nothing more. But this will result in a theme very similar to the default one.
You can choose to add some css classes and some markup just in the places you want something very different from the default theme.
You can also ignore the default theme and build your own markup and css. This way you can get a veeeery custom theme. The downside of this is that you have to spend a lot of time to make everything look good and work.
In the very few themes I implemented I chose to start from the default theme (or blank theme) and just add my own classes and markup where I thought it was needed because the design required it.
Your choice.